# Добавление в бд WEB SQL

Tags: javascript, html

нужна помощь. Есть бд через openDatabase, можно ли сделать так, чтобы кнопка, например в тэге `<a class="a" href="#">`, переносила в таблицу данные из тэгов `<h1>,<h6>`

```
<a class="a" href="Ole">
  <div class="reslov">
    <h1 id="reh1">Название <span> время</span></h1>
    <h6 class="reh6">Дополнение</h6>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Почитайте этот [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm), потом приведите пример Вашего кода, и мы постараемся помочь с его завершением

Comment: Вот вырезал [пример](https://codepen.io/dduckker/pen/arZMWr) из кода, хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "В БД" данные из блока шли в таблицу Recipes. То есть "Recipe" это h1, "link"=ссылка из а, "photo"-ссылка на фото, "time"-время из спана, "ingredients"=h6. А при нажатии на кнопку "Из БД" строка удалялась из табл.

Comment: Отлично, внесите, пожалуйста, то же самое в вопрос, используя линку `править`, а затем кнопку `Фрагмент кода...` из меню редактора. Относительно нажатий на кнопки - добавьте в JS код `click` [event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)